# php reg ex to find data not in html tags but identify html using &lt; and &gt;

Tags: php, html, xml, regex

I have the following data

`<description>&lt;div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on"&gt;&lt;div class="MsoNormal"&gt;&lt;i&gt;&lt;span style="font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif; font-size: xx-small;"&gt;By Marina Correa&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class="MsoNormal"&gt;&lt;i&gt;&lt;span style="font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif; font-size: xx-small;"&gt;Photography: Courtesy the architect&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span style="font-family: Georgia, serif; font-size: 9pt;"&gt;&lt;o:p&gt;&lt;/o:p&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class="MsoNormal"&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tr-caption-container" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;"&gt;&lt;tbody&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td style="text-align: center;"&gt;&lt;a href="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-D1JRy4epwOM/UooCcR-U7lI/AAAAAAAALyM/tDr2ezxnb-I/s1600/Prost_Beer_+House_AH_Design_Indiaartndesign.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"&gt;&lt;img alt="Prost Beer House in Bengaluru, India,by AH design." border="0" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-D1JRy4epwOM/UooCcR-U7lI/AAAAAAAALyM/tDr2ezxnb-I/s1600/Prost_Beer_+House_AH_Design_Indiaartndesign.jpg" title=""&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td class="tr-caption" style="text-align: right;"&gt;&lt;span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: xx-small;"&gt;.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/tbody&gt;&lt;/table&gt;&lt;div class="MsoNormal"&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class="MsoNormal"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style="text-align: justify;"&gt;&lt;span style="font-family: Georgia, &amp;#39;Times New Roman&amp;#39;, serif;"&gt;Evolving from carnage of shipwrecked metal, the interiors of Prost Beer House in Bengaluru, India, make it an attention-grabbing drinking hole…&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;a href="http://inditerrain.indiaartndesign.com/2013/11/beerhouse-rock.html#more"&gt;Read more »&lt;/a&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/IndiaArtNDesign/~4/jGC75D3KB0o" height="1" width="1"/&gt;</description>`

however instead of "<" i have "& lt;" and instead of ">" i have "& gt;"

i need a regular expression to find the data not inside the html tags ie the actual text and not the names of the tags, class name etc...

for parsing the html with "<" and  ">" i found this: (?<=^|>)[^><]+?(?=<|$)

although i dont know how to convert it to suit what i need.
help is much appreciated

Comment: [html_entity_decode();](http://us3.php.net/html_entity_decode) and/or [htmlspecialchars_decode();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) then use a DOM parser to get your data.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like an HTML Fragment inside a XML, more specific inside the description of a RSS feed. If this is the case you should parse the RSS using DOM, this will decode the entities a long the way:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($rss);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
```

Iterate the items:

```
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/rss/channel/item') as $rssItem) {
```

The title of an item is only a text value it can be used directly:

```
  echo 'Title: ', $xpath->evaluate('string(title)', $rssItem), "\n";
```

The description in your example contains the html fragment in a text node with escaped entities, I have seen other example with a CDATA. It doesn't really matter for the outer xml document. It is text and if you read is as text the entities will get transformed back into their respective characters.

```
  $description = $xpath->evaluate('string(description)', $rssItem);
```

So now $description contains < and > again. It can be loaded into a DOM with loadHtml() or just cleaned up with strip_tags().

```
  echo 'Description: ', strip_tags($description), "\n\n";
```

A full example (RSS adapted from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS)):

```
$rss = <<<'RSS'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel> 
 <item>
  <title>Example entry</title>
  <description>Here is some &lt;b&gt;text&lt;/b&gt; containing an interesting &lt;i&gt;description&lt;/i&gt; with &lt;span class="important"&gt;html&lt;/span&gt;.</description>
 </item>
</channel>
</rss>
RSS;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($rss);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/rss/channel/item') as $rssItem) {
  echo 'Title: ', $xpath->evaluate('string(title)', $rssItem), "\n";
  $description = $xpath->evaluate('string(description)', $rssItem);
  echo 'Description: ', strip_tags($description), "\n\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Title: Example entry
Description: Here is some text containing an interesting description with html.
```

Comment: +1 **This** is the only way for profit... Two years since [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/383793), and *still* so many questions with both [tag:xml] *and* [tag:regex] tags.

Answer (score 0):

for decoding you can user htmlspecialchars_decode

for more detail please check http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

To obtain quickly the raw text (without tags) you can do this replacement:

```
$result = preg_replace('~&lt;.*?&gt;~s', ' ', $source);
```

Comment: source and result are outputting exactly the same after trying this.. can u please explain the regex?

Answer (score 0):

This gives you all the texts you're seeking as an array:

```
preg_match_all("/(?<=&gt;)(?!&lt;).*?(?=&lt;)/", $source, $result);
```

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/8z2PQKzNuv) of this regex working with your sample input.